# How to convert a Flow to MutableStateFlow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to keep a mutable state flow in my class, but when I apply any methods to it, it will be converted to an immutable `Flow<T>`:

```kotlin
class MyClass : Listener<String> {

       private val source = Source()

       val flow: Flow<String?>
          get() = _flow

       // region listener
        override fun onUpdate(value: String?) {
            if (value!= null) {
                // emit object changes to the flow
               // not possible, because the builder operators on the flow below convert it to a `Flow` and it doesn't stay as a `MutableSharedFlow` :(
                _flow.tryEmit(value) 
            }
        }
        // end-region

        @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
        private val _flow by lazy {
            MutableStateFlow<String?>(null).onStart {
                emitAll(
                    flow<String?> {
                        val initialValue = source.getInitialValue()
                        emit(initialValue)
                    }.flowOn(MyDispatchers.background)
                )
            }.onCompletion { error ->
                // when the flow is cancelled, stop listening to changes
                if (error is CancellationException) {
                    // is was cancelled
                    source.removeListener(this@MyClass)
                }
            }.apply {
                // listen to changes and send them to the flow
                source.addListener(this@MyClass)
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a way to keep the flow as a `MutableStateFlow` even after I apply the `onCompletion/onStart` methods to it?

Comment: How would you like it to work? After applying transformations to a flow, the resulting flow uses the first one as its source. So how would it work that the resulting flow replicates data from another flow and at the same time it is directly mutable? Or maybe you just mean to apply some transformations, but return the source flow?

Comment: I want a flow that I can emit on within my class, listen to changes and emit those to the flow from within this class, and also listen to when the flow was cancelled so I can stop listening to changes. It seems like there is no way to do it, if there is can you show me?

Comment: Is `source.getInitialValue()` suspending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you apply transformations to a mutable state flow, the resulting flow becomes read-only because the original flow acts as its source. If you want to manually emit events, you need to emit them to the initial source flow.

That being said, it seems what you want to achieve here is quite simple: bridging a callback based API to a `Flow` API. There is a built-in function in Kotlin coroutines to do that, which is called [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html).

I'm not sure how your source API handles backpressure, but it would look something like this:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun Source.asFlow(): Flow<String?> = callbackFlow {
    send(getInitialValue())

    val listener = object : Listener<String> {
        override fun onUpdate(value: String?) {
            if (value != null) {
                trySend(value)
            }
        }
    }
    addListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        removeListener(listener)
    }
}
```

Or maybe with `runBlocking { send(value) }` instead of `trySend()`, depending on how `Source` handles backpressure and blocking in its own thread pool.

Note that `flowOn` might be used on top of this flow, but it would only really matter for `getInitialValue()`, because the thread that executes the callback is controlled by the `Source` anyway.

If adding many listeners is expensive for the `Source`, you might also consider sharing this flow using the `shareIn()` operator, so multiple subsccribers share the same listener subscription.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this `extension` function will solve your problem

```
public fun <T> Flow<T>.mutableStateIn(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    initialValue: T
): MutableStateFlow<T> {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(initialValue)

    scope.launch {
        this@mutableStateIn.collect(flow)
    }

    return flow
}
```